# Opening a file and storing a message. Reading the message into a string variable to print. Java/Netbeans

Tags: java, input, netbeans, output

Hey I needed some help with this exercise I'm working on. I have to open a file with the name hello.txt then store the message "Hello World!" in the file. Then I have to close the file and open it, and read the message into a string variable to print it. So far I have this code below. Do you have any suggestions on how I can successfully compile this code?

```
package ProgrammingExercise11;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        File inputFile = new File(hello.txt);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(hello.txt);
        out.println("Hello, World!");
        String line = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: If your code does not compile, then tell us the error message(s) that your compiler gave you.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Let's answer your question.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        File inputFile = new File(hello.txt);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(hello.txt);
        out.println("Hello, World!");
        String line = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

Your code does not compile because you have introduced two variables with the same name `in` and you did not declare `hello.txt`.
To solve it following your idea.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String filePath = "hello.txt";
            File inputFile = new File(filePath);

            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(inputFile);
            printWriter.write("Hello World!");
            printWriter.close();

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile.getPath());
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = buf.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            is.close();
            buf.close();

    }
```

Welcome to java world!

Answer (score 0):

The Files Class since Java 7 provides static methods that operate on files, directories, or other types of files, which is more simple and flexible.

```
String file = "hello.txt";
Path filePath = Paths.get(file);
if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
    try(OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)){
        // write message to file.
        String message = "Hello World!";
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes();
        fos.write(messageBytes);

        // read message from file.
        byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(receivedBytes);
        System.out.println(new String(receivedBytes));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```